# Getting errors when using Equals on generic parameters with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, struct

I have the following two generic classes:

```
 public abstract class Entity<T> : IEntity<T>, IAuditableEntity,ISoftDeletable where T : struct
    {
        public T Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    }


    public abstract class Repository<TEntity,TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey> where TEntity :Entity<TKey> where TKey : struct           
    {
        protected DbContext Context;
        protected readonly IDbSet<TEntity> Set;

        protected Repository(DbContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
            Set = Context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public TEntity Get(TKey key)
        {               
            var output = Set.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id.Equals(key));
            return output ;
        }
    }
```

My problem is the Get method. I keep getting this error

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

i tried to use == but it wont compile and says

> cannot apply == to operands TKey and TKey

Why isnt this working? my TKey is supposed to be a primitive data type, isnt the limiter where TKey:struct the correct one?

Why is the compiler using Equals(object) when there is Equals(int), which is what this key is?

Comment: Your `IDbSet` does not know anything of `TKey`, so it cannot apply `==` to the property `Id` (which I doubt is of type `TKey`).

Comment: How so, if i have
protected readonly IDbSet<TEntity> Set;
 and  
where TEntity :Entity<TKey> where TKey : struct ??

Comment: Well, id is 1, and i don't know why you doubt Id is of type TKey. Care to elaborate?

Comment: o.Id is of type T (at least it says to in your Entity declaration, key, is of type TKey.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro: the names used as constraint parameters have no more meaning than the names of method parameters. You don't need to use the same name in two separate declarations. In this case, the declaration of `Repository` says that the first constraint parameter `TEntity` must be of type `Entity<TKey>`, and so the second constraint parameter (`TKey`) becomes the first/only constraint parameter to `Entity<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `==` comparison fails because that operator can only be used for predefined value types or for reference types, and your `TKey` is neither.

You say in your comment that `TKey` is an `int`. That may be true in *your* case, but a user of your class(es) could define an `Entity<List<string>.Enumerator>` since `List<T>.Enumerator` is a `struct`. The mind boggles at what "equals" means in that case.

My point is that the compiler has no way to know, **at compile time**, how to do anything other than use `object.Equals`.

I wonder why you're constraining the key type to be a `struct` anyway. The most common types of ID that I've seen are `int` and `string`. By using a `struct` you're already ruling out `string`...

Do you really need the flexibility to support keys that are not integers? If not, your classes could be much simpler.

---

**Update**: you could constrain your `TKey` such that it implements `IComparable`, since all the numeric types implement that. That would then let you use `CompareTo` within the implementation of your `Get` method.

However, since the lambda you pass to `FirstOrDefault` will actually be executed on the database side, I'm not sure what will happen, i.e. whether EF will be able to translate that to a SQL expression correctly.

```
public abstract class Entity<T> : IEntity<T>, IAuditableEntity,ISoftDeletable where T : struct, IComparable

public abstract class Repository<TEntity,TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey> where TEntity :Entity<TKey> where TKey : struct, IComparable
```

Comment: I really dont care if i use == or Equals,  what i need is a way to compare the existing ID with the given parameter. The reason my entities have that T:struct constraint is that i have a fair amount of tables that have byte keys (lookup tables) and s decent amount of long keys. so basically i have a kinda even distribuition of tinyints, ints and longs as keys at database level. i can alter the db, but not the keys.

Comment: And i dont think Repository<List<string>.Enumerator>  is possible since  List<string>.Enumerator does not derive from  Entity<T>. Could be wrong, but...

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Entity<List<string>.Enumerator>', the point being that since `TKey` is only constrained to be a `struct`, it allows all manner of crazy stuff.

Comment: ended up using (object)o.Id == (object)key but i doubt there is an uglier hack on the face of the earth

Comment: I'm kind of in the same situation myself, and I'm glad I found this workaround, but have you by any chance come up with any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the `IDbSet.Find` method, which takes one or more `object`-typed key values.

```
public TEntity Get(TKey key)
{               
    return Set.Find(key);
}
```

This has the additional advantage that it's more efficient if the entity already exists in the `DbContext`'s local cache (since it avoids an unnecessary trip to the database).

However, I suspect you're going to want to do more than just retrieve individual items, so you'll probably run into the same problem later.

Comment: yup. i just posted the get method but the rabbit hole does deeper