# System.Object constant cannot be created in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I try to write code that will iterate through my `DbSet<staffCompetence>` but it doesn't work.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(StaffWrapper sw, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var st = db.staff.Where(s => s.ID.Equals(sw.Id)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (st != null)
    {
        var cvs = TokenBoxExtension.GetSelectedValues<Guid>("StaffCompetenceTokenBox");
        UpdateCompetenceLinks(st.ID, cvs);
        //Rewrite values...

        db.Entry(st).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View(sw);
}

private void UpdateCompetenceLinks(Guid staffId, Guid[] ids)
{
    var model = db.staffCompetence;

    for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; ++i)
    {
        var id = ids[i];
        //On line below it crashes
        var scs = model.Where(s => s.competenceID.Equals(id)).ToList(); //ToList() for test

        if (!scs.Any())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes in the `if` condition with exception `NotSupported` and a message that it can't create `System.Object` constant in this context.
What does it mean? And how to fix it?

**P.S.** I use Russian located debugger, so I can't post a log.
**ADDED**

> Исключение типа "System.NotSupportedException" возникло в
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll, но не было обработано в коде
>   пользователя
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Не удалось создать константу с типом
>   "System.Object". В этом контексте поддерживаются только типы-примитивы
>   и типы перечисления.

In English:

> The exception of "System.NotSupportedException" type appears in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll, but it was not handled by the user code.
>
> Details: The constant creation with 
>   "System.Object" type failed. In this context type-premitives and iteration types support only.

P.P.S I translated as I can.

Comment: Have you tried `if (scs.Any())` instead?

Comment: It crashes on any method that it has. In another places but without a loop it works

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477049/getting-errors-when-using-equals-on-generic-parameters-with-ef)

Comment: I think problem with db context other than inside `if`. Because when you call FirstAndDefault() then it try to access db to get data. Can you test scs.ToList() working or not

Comment: Please edit your post and publish the full exception message.

Comment: You can consider: a) using FirstOrDefault to make sure that your list REALLY has a value.   b) Try to use CompareTo for a Guid value.    c) If your competence is type of nullable, please use HasValue to check first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You codes can be simplified to something like this following:

```
using (dbPMEntities db = new dbPMEntities())
{
var model = db.staffCompetence;

foreach (Guid id in ids)
{
    **var scs = model.FirstOrDefault(s => s.competenceID.HasValue?s.competenceID.CompareTo(id):null);   //Do double-check to see whether the competenceID is of a real value……and check firstOrDefault()**

    if (scs==null)
    {
        var item = new staffCompetence();
        item.recID = Guid.NewGuid();
        item.competenceID = id;
        model.Add(item);
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare `System.Guid` directly. Do compare using `Guid.CompareTo` instead

```
dbPMEntities db = new dbPMEntities();
var model = db.staffCompetence;

foreach (Guid id in ids)
{
    var scs = model.Where(s => s.competenceID.CompareTo(id) > 0);

    if (!scs.Any())
    {
        var item = new staffCompetence();
        item.recID = Guid.NewGuid();
        item.competenceID = id;
        model.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Guid` supports `Equals` perfectly. And `Any()` crashes too.